# Looking for joomla flight search extension

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I have kept on searching for flight searching extension for a while and I can not find the joomla flight search extension (no need booking function).

Where can I find it?

Should I start learning php, xml, mysql to build an extension? I have a little programming background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one that I know of. You will have to pick an API that works for you and write a component to query it. This is a little dated but the info and links are accurate for finding a flight search API - http://blog.programmableweb.com/2007/10/29/5-travel-apis-from-comparison-to-booking/